# dribbble authentication url not working in android

Tags: android, authentication, callbackurl, dribbble-api

This is api doc. http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/oauth/

This is client Ids:

Client ID

```
3acdea730eaae4ea51dadf296be4e8edf7cd4b6ab030ce69c1de0d1a335b679d
```

Client Secret

```
4a9773911cd2304fa23047e703e35fffbd443f32a9c73207aa60b45852e17b64
```

Client Access Token

```
57fe6dc09292e4dadce94a3dc9fd895117792a48f7194bbc5b8bd229e6ef1388
```

Java code

```
String LOGIN_CALLBACK = "placeholder.com";
String LOGIN_URL = "https://dribbble.com/oauth/authorize?client_id="
            + "3acdea730eaae4ea51dadf296be4e8edf7cd4b6ab030ce69c1de0d1a335b679d"
            + "&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F" + LOGIN_CALLBACK
            + "&scope=public+write+comment+upload";

context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(LOGIN_URL)));
```

in manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".DribbbleLogin"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="dribbble-auth-callback"
                    android:scheme="plain" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

what should be put in callback url and what should be passed in redirect url, so that the flow redirect to my app?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 2):

Your callbackUrl should be like `plain://example.com` and there is one more thing that needs to be done in the android manifest

```
android:host="example.com"
android:scheme="plain"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put in callbackurl "plain://example.com"

in manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".DribbbleLogin"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:scheme="plain" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

In DribbbleLogin Activity

```
String loginCallback = "electedface.com";
String code;
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null
                && intent.getData() != null
                && !TextUtils.isEmpty(intent.getData().getAuthority())
                && loginCallback.equals(intent.getData().getAuthority())) {
    code = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("code");
}
```

Call login url "https://dribbble.com//oauth/token" with dribbble_client_id, dribbble_client_secret and this code. you will get access_token, token_type, scope in json.

Thanks All